# Location overwriting FilesMatch

Tags: apache

I have a location container which is overwriting a filematch directive.  I understand location containers are evaluated last and therefore this is expected behaviour.

However, I am wanting to grant access to a location based on a certain set of rules EXCEPT when the request is for certain filetypes in which case I want to allow all requests.

```
   <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      ... a handful of allow/deny details here ...
   </Location>

   <FilesMatch ".+\.(css|js)$">
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </FilesMatch>
```

How can I accomplish what I am after?

Comment: there are two options: `<LocationMatch>` and `<If>`. `<LocationMatch ".\.(?:css|js)$">` or `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /.\.(?:css|js)$/">`

Answer (score 0):

As per Deadooshka's comment, the solution was LocationMatch

```
   <LocationMatch ".+\.(css|js)$">
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </LocationMatch>
```